# ValueError Django CSV

Tags: django, python-3.x, csv

All I'm trying to do is through Django display my CSV table on the page.
And everything seems to work, but for some reason I get an error and I can’t find a solution to it

```
ValueError: The view csv_app.views.csv_simple_read didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[19/Feb/2020 21:40:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 57986
```

I'm new to django. I would be very grateful for any help.

**Views.py**

```
import csv
import os

def csv_simple_read(request):
 path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
 file = os.path.join(path, 'csv_simple_read.csv')

 with open(file) as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
  line_count = 0
  for row in csv_reader:
    print('\n\nColumn names are {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
    line_count += 1
```

**csv_simple_read.csv**

```
test3;2020-02-16;05:22:49;OK
test2;2020-02-16;05:22:25;OK
test1;2020-02-16;05:22:10;OK
test3;2020-02-16;05:22:49;OK
test2;2020-02-16;05:22:25;OK
test1;2020-02-16;05:22:10;OK
```

**csv_home.html**

```
 <body>
 <h3>CSV Example - Read Write Examples</h3>
 <ul>
 <br>
 <li>Read Operation
 <ul>
 <li>
 <a href="{% url 'csv_simple_read' %}">Simple CSV Read Operation</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 {{csv_data}}
 {% if csv_data %}
 sad
 {{csv_data}}
 {% endif %}
 </body>
```

Comment: Exactly Anni you've not returned HttpResponse to `csv_simple_read`. All you have to do is return the `csv_home.html` file. `return render(request, "csv_home.html", {context_dict_in_case_to_show_csv_result})`

Comment: Many thanks for the help! I added your line of code at the end of views.py, but unfortunately nothing has changed. Code does not see `render` @RajaSimon

Comment: Did you import in the top of your views.py file? `from django.shortcuts import render`

Comment: No, at the end. 
Yes, I already did it, right after I answered. 
Now there is a problem with `{context_dict_in_case_to_show_csv_result}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's change your view code a bit for transferring from Python to HTML.

```
with open(file) as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
  line_count = 0
  resultlist = []
  for row in csv_reader:
    resultdict = {}
    resultdict['name'] = row[0]
    resultdict['date'] = row[1]
    resultdict['time'] = row[2]
    resultdict['status'] = row[3]
    resultlist.append(resultdict)

    line_count += 1
return render(request, "csv_home.html", {'results': resultlist})
```

In your HTML file you can do this

```
{% for result in results %}
    {{ result.name }}
    {{ result.date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't suit `append`:


`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 68106`

Comment: Changed the answer try now.

Comment: There is! He brought out the data! True in a terrible form, but nonetheless, he finally displayed the data from the table. Thank you very much! @RajaSimon